# Recovering "invisible" files from external HDD

Tags: ubuntu, ls, external-hdd, ntfs-3g

My external HDD (WD Elements) just went into a strange state and I am asking this question to see if anyone can make sense of this.

I was running a long job overnight which reads some large files from this HDD, processes them, and then writes a few smaller files back to the HDD. In the morning, after the job has finished, it appeared as if most files were deleted from the external drive.

Using dolphin or `ls` only some of the files the job was supposed to write were there, the others weren't. Additionally, all large files, that the job was only supposed to read, were missing.

However, the job should have failed if one of the large files had been deleted. And indeed I can actually read these "non-existent" files if I type in their name from memory (*e.g.* I was able to just `cp` them to another location).
The job had finished successfully and all files were written, but tools like `ls` just wouldn't show them (I also tried un- and remounting).

I solved this problem by remembering file paths but is there a way to recover if you don't remember these files?

I am on on Ubuntu 22.04 and the external HDD has ntfs3:

```
$ df -hT
...
/dev/sdb1               ntfs3     1,9T  863G 1001G  47% /media/marc/Elements
```

**Edit**

The job was a python script that was reading grib files using `pupygrib` and nc files using `netCDF4`. All grib and nc files were not found by `ls` later on (even though they were still there).
For `pupygrib` I `open(..., "rb")` a filehandle in python, `netCDF4` opens a file in C with `"r"` mode.

For writing, the python script used `pyarrow` to write parquet files. Some of these files "got missing" (even though, as mentioned, they were actually still there).
As far as I can see `pyarrow` uses `open(..., 'wb')` in python to open a file for writing .

While copying files back around in the HDD I just noticed that some files also seem to disappear after renaming them (using `mv`). I don't notice any systematic disappearing though (e.g. that certain names tend to disappear).
All pathnames consist of only characters a-Z, numbers 0-9, `_`, `/`, `.`, `-`.
The longest pathname is 110 characters long.

**Smartmontools**

```
$ sudo smartctl -q noserial -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-10022-tuxedo] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD20SDRW-11VUUS0
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    2.000.365.379.584 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Feb  3 13:07:08 2024 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (14640) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 298) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   196   190   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3158
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       216
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       316
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       51
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2773
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       316         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: In order for anyone to know what's going on, edit the question and add the commands that were supposedly run by the job, what they were supposed to do, what was supposed to happen, and what actually happened. If there are any logs to which the activity was sent, include that as well.

Comment: try: `find /media/marc/Elements/ -ls | cat -ve` (the cat -ve is in case some weird chars (often: ^M) mess up the name display) and see if you see all of your files somewhere. Then another run with "LC_ALL=C" in front of the find : `LC_ALL=C find /media/marc/Elements/ -ls | cat -ve`

Comment: Shows the same files.

Could it maybe also just be an indication that this HDD is at the end of its life? (bought it used and has been around for a while now)

Comment: You can check drive's status: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools
In Disks alias gnome-disks you can click on icon in upper right corner and see Smart Status
https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Howto_ReadSmartctlReports_ATA_542.1
 Do you have names that are not valid in NTFS? Are you mounting with windows_names,big_writes parameters? And are you using python where rsync may be better. I like python, but use rsync for any large copy of files, often in a script, so I can remember parameters. Note that NTFS does not support Linux ownership & permissions.

Comment: I added a short test result above (will do long later). All pathnames consist of only characters a-Z, numbers 0-9, `_`, `/`, `.`, `-`. As far as I can see from the libraries I use, they don't use rsync. For `pupygrib` I `open(..., "rb")` a filehandle, `netCDF4` opens a file in C with `"r"` mode, and `pyarrow` uses `open(..., 'wb')` in python to open a file for writing.